# how to automate app-distribution "get started button" in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-app-distribution

Currenty iam building some android apps automatically, but somehow blocked by this error App Distribution could not find your app . Make sure to onboard your app by pressing the "Get started" button on the App Distribution page in the Firebase console: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/appdistribution. i need to open browser and press get stared button.

any idea to make it automatically using CLI ?

try few command in firebase cli but didnt work